# Loading a precise version of the soliidity compiler

Tags: javascript, solidity

**Context** : i'm trying to build a smart contract verification system which queries the blockchain about a given contract and then compares the deployed bytecode with the bytecode provided by the user (the whole thing resides on a Node.js server).

**Problem**: I found out that there is the possibility for the developers to run an arbitrary chosen solidity compiler through the usage of the command **solc.looadRemoteVersion(version, callback)** but no matter what I do, i keep getting the following error when calling the upmentioned method: **Error retrieving binaries : not found**.

What I understand is that solc is unable to locate where the binaries are saved (but the little docs I read actually say that if you have the latest installed then, sold should *automagically* have also older versions..)

And even if the latest version does not have all of its previous versions loaded, where should I put the different versions of the compilers in order for the command to really work?

[image: This is a snapshot of my code which is really autoesplicative itself]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who were asking, the solution that worked for me was what follows:

The input for the remote compiler version needs to be something like "**v**0.8.9+commit0.9...." (this also works for nightly versions of the compiler, I tried).
Well turns out that if you compile your contract using hardat, that initial **"v"** is omitted by default.

So be careful when dealing with Hardat and solc versions !